# Shapeless 2.3.5+ can't provide implicit for Generic.Aux

Tags: scala, shapeless

After updating to Shapeless 2.3.5+ code that used to work stopped compiling. I boiled it down to a minimal, yet still somewhat complicated example:

```
import shapeless._

trait A
trait B[+A1 <: A]
case class C[T]()

case class D[A1 <: A, B1 <: B[A1]](c: C[B1]) {  
  def bind() = D.bind(this)
}

object D {
  def bind[T, L <: HList](t: T)(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[T, L]) = ???
}
```

It fails due to the following:

```
shapeless.this.Generic.materialize is not a valid implicit value for shapeless.Generic.Aux[D[A1,B1],L] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,B1] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [A1 <: A,B1 <: B[A1]]
```

It compiles if `B[A1]` in the type parameters is replaced with `B[_]`, or `C[B1]` is replaced with `C[B[A1]]`, but these are not exactly equivalent. I can't really figure out why it infers `Nothing` and what can be done about it, and whether it's a problem with my code or a regression in Shapeless.

Comment: I think it would be better to file an issue in their Github repo.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I guess. Shapeless is still a bit like black magic to me, so I blame my skills and understanding first :)

Comment: Fair enough, then I would ask first in the **discord** server: https://discord.gg/RmdjDGdP - duh, just saw you already did, my bad.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, no, that's and absolutely reasonable suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem too active, so I tried to widen the outreach here. But if I don't hear back or come up with anything in a day or two, I'll file a Github issue.

Comment: The code compiles in Scala 2.13.8 + Shapeless 2.3.9 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/aZ4lbmNUSGycg1VhQyeZYw/2